# setContentView not working in my android code

Tags: android

I have an error in my android code..my setContentView is not working.
my code is setContentView(R.layout.secondlayout);
Error is secondlayout cannot be resolved or it is not a feild.

Comment: post your secondlayout.xml

Comment: have you imprtet the correct R?

Comment: make sure you import statement for R is your package and not android.R

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you placed the secondlayout.xml file inside res -> layout folder. Also make sure there is no error in this file. If the below line is there in your import statements, remove it.

```
import android.R;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

import com.example.appname.R

Then, in eclipse go to project>clean , choose your project and press OK. Then wait until it is done. The clean operation regenrates R.